# Spring @RequestParam mapping Boolean based on 1 or 0 instead of true or false

Tags: spring, request, boolean, http-request-parameters

Why is Spring 3.2 only mapping my Boolean based on that the requestparam is "0" or "1" ?

```
@RequestParam(required= false, defaultValue = "false") Boolean preview
```

Preview will only be `"true"` when the requestparam is `"?preview=1"` which is wierd

I want it to be `"?preview=true"`. How do I do that?

Comment: did you know a way, where the request parameter which has default value and required is false, that can be totally ignored in the URL, meaning we don't even have to put anything in the URL for that request parameter.

In your example, `preview` will not even be a part of the URL.

Answer (score 110):

I think we may need more detail in order to be effective answering your question.

I have working Spring 3.2 code along the lines of:

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/foo/{id}", method = RequestMethod.GET)
@ResponseBody
public Foo getFoo(
    @PathVariable("id") String id, 
    @RequestParam(value="bar", required = false, defaultValue = "true")
        boolean bar)
{ 
    ... 
}
```

Spring correctly interprets `?bar=true`, `?bar=1`, or `?bar=yes` as being true, and `?bar=false`, `?bar=0`, or `?bar=no` as being false.

True/false and yes/no values ignore case.

Comment: Does it do equalsIgnoreCase as well? I mean what would be expected result if I send `bar=TRUE` ,`bar=TrUe`  or `bar=yES`...?

Comment: According to the sorucecode linked by Pavel below, it ignores case.

Comment: Just a small info:
Supplying a defaultValue implicitly sets required as false.
So don't need to pass `required=false`.

Answer (score 24):

Spring should be able to interpret *true*, *1*, *yes* and *on* as `true` boolean value... check [StringToBooleanConverter](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-framework/blob/master/spring-core/src/main/java/org/springframework/core/convert/support/StringToBooleanConverter.java).

Comment: is there a way in which, we turn required off and provide a default value and in the URL we don't even have to mention the request parameter?

Comment: {{@RequestParam(defaultValue = "true") boolean notify}}

Should suffice to solve your problem.

Comment: @SoumitriPattnaik Supplying a default value implicitly sets required to false.

Answer (score 0):

you can use jackson's JsonDeserialize annotation, short and clean

create the following deserializer:

```
public class BooleanDeserializer extends JsonDeserializer<Boolean> {
    public BooleanDeserializer() {
    }

    public Boolean deserialize(JsonParser parser, DeserializationContext context) throws IOException {
        return !"0".equals(parser.getText());
    }
}
```

and add the annotation to your DTO like so:

```
public class MyDTO {
    @NotNull
    @JsonDeserialize(using = BooleanDeserializer.class)
    private Boolean confirmation;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

We can do using

```
@GetMapping("/getAudioDetails/organizations/{orgId}/interactions/{interactionId}")
public ResponseEntity<?> getAudioDetails(@PathVariable("orgId") String orgId,@PathVariable("interactionId") String interactionId,
        @RequestParam(name = "verbose", required = false, defaultValue = "false") boolean verbose){
    System.out.println(verbose);
    return null;
}
```

where verbose is an boolean flag which by default happens to be false as can be referred from inage below on api call .[image]

Answer (score 0):

I suppose you are missing value="preview" in the @RequestParam. Due to this, Spring is setting the variable **preview** to **false** always, as that is the defaultValue.

`@RequestParam(value = "preview", required= false, defaultValue = "false") Boolean preview`